# Click a button if text exist in page with iMacros

Tags: imacros

I am trying to use iMacros with Firefox to click an UnFollow button ONLY if this code exist on the page...

```
<small class="follow-status">follows you</small>
```

If the above does not exist in the page source then it would run this iMacros code...

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:UnFollow
```

From what I have read, there is no if/else type syntax but you can run Javascript with

```
EVAL("Javascript code here")
```

If anyone knows how I could do this I could really use the help

Comment: you mean "If the above **EXIST** in the page source then it would run this iMacros code...", right?

Answer (score 7):

You can trick Imacros to make an If statement, but first you have to `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` for this macro. Then:

```
SET EXTRACT NULL
'if this exist you extract the text(even if you know it)
'if doesn't exist should return error but we turned that off; Extract remains Null
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:follows<SP>you EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if(text==\"follows you\") text = \"jibber\";else text = \"UnFollow\";text;")
'this one executes if the text is right, if not should give error but we turned that off
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:{{!VAR1}}
```

Comment: i had a similar problem now i know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Use a javascript file for this

```
run();
function run() {
  var exists = doesElementExist();
  alert('element exists? ' + exists);
  if (exists) {
    iimPlay('CODE: TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:UnFollow');
  }
  else {
    // do something else here
  }
}

// test if element exists
function doesElementExist() {
  iimDisplay('looking for small element with class "follow-status" on page');
  var code = iimPlay('CODE: SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1\n'
                     + 'TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=CLASS:follow-status EXTRACT=TXT');
  if (code !==1) {
    return false;
  }
  var extract = iimGetLastExtract();
  if (extract === '#EANF#') {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```