# I need an imacros script that will click a link if text appears in the web page, then battle. else move on

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have been looking for days and cannot find a way to do what I need to do. I am a javascript n00b... This came very close, but I don't understand how to integrate the below functionality into it, as well as integrate it into the rest of my script. [Click a button if text exist in page with iMacros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525640/click-a-button-if-text-exist-in-page-with-imacros/13617472#13617472)

Could someone please help me create a script that will open a page, click a link, if certain text appears then click another link, or else continue on to the next link/page?

Here is what I am looking to do:

```
TAB=T1

GOTO URL=[heal]

TAB OPEN

TAB=T2

URL GOTO=[enemy link]

'battle (pos=1 is always 1)'

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/battle ATTR=NAME:commit

'here is where I run into my issue with if/then/else statements'
```

IF text (or ALT text) = injured, suicide, dead, etc. THEN move on to next script item ELSE battle again

```
TAB CLOSE

TAB=T1

[heal]

TAB OPEN

TAB=T2

GOTO URL=[next enemy link]

[Repeat the battle, if/then/else, and move on]

'Eventually, after maybe 100 of the above, I would like a random wait (below is 24-36 hours)'

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*43200 + 86400); randomNumber;")
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}

[entire script repeats via the Play Loop button]
```

This is probably a lot to ask, but `IF` someone can help this javascript n00b get the if/then/else javascript written `AND` get it to transition to/from javascript and the normal imacros commands listed `THEN` I would be forever grateful. `ELSE` I will still appreciate the efforts :-)

Comment: Consider formatting your question so that it becomes easier to read.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Plus you can use search to find an answer. Tons of similar questions. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imacros+javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using Firefox as your browser, if so, go to the view menu, and select the sidebar>iOpus iMacros button, this will bring up the imacros menu in the left hand pane. Go to the game you are playing in the right hand pane, and on the left pane select the Rec tab on the bottom, then select the record button, then in your right hand pane, make the selections that you normally would and imacros will record each button you select to accomplish your goals, from there you will be well on your way...