# How to EXTRACT and save Url in CSV using IMACROS

Tags: csv, twitter, imacros

**Trying to get contents  and saving them in a CSV, one per row**
**But when it has a WEBLINK, the URL gets messed up.**

See the latest

Actually the glassdoor.com/Top-Companies-... part is a hyperlink to following weblink

> http://t.co/tDbVGX48c6

which redirects to

> http://www.glassdoor.com/Top-Companies-for-Culture-and-Values-LST_KQ0,36.htm

**ISSUE is if we use the following to save this **

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:dir-ltr EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Save.csv
```

it is saved in CSV as following only (i.e TEXT) & the link is not saved properly.

```
Honored to be named @Glassdoor's top company for culture and values. #jointheflock glassdoor.com/Top-Companies-...
```

**How can we make sure we get ACTUAL link saved in CSV, for every one

I feel EVAL & thus Javascript command can be used but i am not sure how.
I am using WINDOWS XP 64 Bit with Latest Firefox Imacros Addon
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [EXTRACT](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#The_EXTRACT_Parameter) definition on the iMacros wiki.  You can use HREF as the extract type to extract the link instead of the text for that anchor.  The following example extracts the link and saved it to a file.

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.penny-arcade.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Forum EXTRACT=HREF
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=FORUMS.CSV
```

Here is the macro code for the twitter page:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:twitter-timeline-link EXTRACT=HREF
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=SaveTweets.csv
```

Here is a javascript version that pulls each tweet and a link it if exists.

```
var retcode, tagText, tweetCounter, startIndex, endIndex, macro, extractMacro;

extractMacro = "";
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "URL GOTO=https://twitter.com/twitter\n";

retcode = iimPlay(macro);

tweetCounter = 1;
do
{
    extractMacro = "CODE:";

    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "TAG POS=" + tweetCounter + " TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:ProfileTweet-text<SP>js-tweet-text<SP>u-dir EXTRACT=TXT\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);
    tagText = iimGetLastExtract();

    // iMacros code requires <SP> for spaces
    tagText = tagText.replace(/[ \s\t\n]/g, "<SP>");
    // Add extracted value to another macro for extraction later
    extractMacro += "ADD !EXTRACT " + tagText + "\n";
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "TAG POS=" + tweetCounter + " TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:ProfileTweet-Contents EXTRACT=HTM\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);
    tagHTML = iimGetLastExtract();
    tweetCounter++;

    startIndex = 0;
    do
    {
        startIndex = tagHTML.indexOf("data-expanded-url=", startIndex + 1);
        endIndex = tagHTML.indexOf(" ", startIndex);
        if (startIndex > 0)
        {
            var linkText = tagHTML.substring(startIndex + 'data-expanded-url="'.length, endIndex - 1);
            // iMacros code requires <SP> for spaces
            linkText = linkText.replace(/[ \s\t\n]/g, "<SP>");
            extractMacro += "ADD !EXTRACT " + linkText + "\n";
        }
    } while (startIndex > 0);

    // Save extracted data
    extractMacro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=SaveTweets.csv\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(extractMacro);
}
while (tagText !== "#EANF#");
```

Comment: i tried HREF command you provided but it didnt work . It gave a #EANF# error .Sorry but if you could try on the twitter handle to fetch a tweet into csv, it would be better.

Comment: @SuperUserMan updated my answer to reflect your case, HREF is the extraction type you want to use for this problem, you have to make sure you are referencing the proper element with the [TAG](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG) logic.

Comment: thanks for reply. It worked BUT there came another issue. All of the tweets may not be having a weblink, which this class "twitter-timeline-link " refers too (some may be having just text). In that case TAG finds #EANF# . Can we in some way (say java script/EVAL) make sure to save that class only when it exists (i.e only when a tweet has a link in it), else simply EXTRACT TXT. Thanks. Plz reply soon i have been waiting for ur replies

Comment: There is another thing too that using HREF only fetches the link not the text. I searched and got something on the lines of IF then statements here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525640/click-a-button-if-text-exist-in-page-with-imacros , Can you help make a solution for this scenario when there is no link and when only TXT needs to be fetch, it fetches/saves TXT whereas when both TXT and LINK are present, it fetches both TXT and HREF as extract. Thanks

Comment: You can use the HTM option that will extract all of the html for each tweet which will contain all the text and any link information.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But its posting some columns per line in CSV and also looks like startindex is not getting increased by 1. Further instead of "data-expanded-url" can we simply use "href" which is a shorterned version of expanded url? Also if page loads more tweets till the last POS TAG is loading, this twittercounter goes on and on and script never ends till all tweets of a an account are over. Can we set a for loop of some kind to end the counter at say 50 tweets or so. Thanks.

Comment: Give it a shot, let me know how it goes.